# C++ Tree traversal: Why Looping is slower than Recursion in this case?

Tags: c++, performance, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I need to traverse a tree in my C++ code for a large number of times, the depth of the tree can vary from one iteration to another. I might also conditionally early break from the tree traversal. While profiling my code (using Visual studio compiler), I noticed that the tree traversal part was the biggest bottleneck in my code so I need to speed that part as much as I can.

Below is the description and a simplified runnable version of my code to showcase the issue I currently have.

While using recursion, I noticed that I might be able to speed up my code by conditionally early-breaking from the recursion. However, my implementation of the early-break didn't improve the speed at all (see the code). I thought by using a loop instead of recursion, early-breaking will be easier to implement, so I translated my tree traversal to a loop. Surprisingly, the loop version was an order of magnitude slower than the recursion version! Also, early-break did only improve the speed by 10% at most which is surprising because this is a depth first search traversal, when the break happens, a large part of the tree is not traversed. Hence, at least a speed-up of 50-100% is expected.

My questions:

1. Why in the specific case below the looped version is an order of
   magnitude slower?!
2. Why early break doesn't improve speed much (both for the loop and the recursion)
3. Any other performance tips for the case below is deeply appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class Node {
public:
    int id;
    int left = -1;
    int right = -1;
    int count = 0;

    Node(int _id) { id = _id; }
};
std::vector<Node> nodes;

//1) recursive tree traversal
void recursive(int node) {
    if (nodes[node].left == -1) {
        nodes[node].count++;
    }
    else {
        recursive(nodes[node].right);
        recursive(nodes[node].left);
    }
}

//2) recursive tree traversal with conditional break
void recursive2(int node, bool* stop) {
    if (*stop == false) {
        if (nodes[node].left == -1) {
            nodes[node].count++;
            if (rand() % 2 == 0) { *stop = true; } //conditional break
        }
        else {
            recursive2(nodes[node].right, stop);
            if (*stop == false) {
                recursive2(nodes[node].left, stop);
            }
        }
    }
}

// loop traversal
void loop(int node) {
    stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(node);
    while (stack.size() > 0) {
        node = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        if (nodes[node].left == -1) {
            nodes[node].count++;
            //if (rand() % 2 == 0) { break; } // conditional break
        }
        else {
            stack.push(nodes[node].right);
            stack.push(nodes[node].left);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        nodes.push_back(Node(i));
    }
    // make a simple tree /node 6 is the root
    nodes[4].left = nodes[0].id;
    nodes[4].right = nodes[1].id;
    nodes[5].left = nodes[2].id;
    nodes[5].right = nodes[3].id;
    nodes[6].left = nodes[4].id;
    nodes[6].right = nodes[5].id;


    /// speed comparison 
    int n = 10000000;
    int root_node = 6;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { recursive(root_node); }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "recursion:" << duration.count() << endl;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bool stop = false;
        recursive2(root_node, &stop);
    }
    stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "recursion with early-break:" << duration.count() << endl;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { loop(root_node); }
    stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "loop:" << duration.count() << endl;
}
```

Comment: The tree you are traversing is so small compared to the number of iterations you are running that managing the dynamic memory of the stack object dwarves any gains you get from doing it in a loop. (drafting a full answer)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my code, I generally deal with trees that are 2-3 times deeper than the given example. The performance characteristics is similar to the one posted. Does that mean unless I have very deep trees, recursion will always be better in my case? Also, is it because the shallow tree depth I'm not getting benefit from the early break too?

Comment: Not necessarily. It just means that you need to be more efficient with how dynamic memory is allocated. A low-hanging fruit would be: by default `std::stack<>` uses a `std::deque` for storage, which has some notoriously slow implementation on some compilers. switching to std::stack(int, std::vector<int>` could potentially make a world of difference. For small trees, a static buffer would be even better.

Comment: If I find that container traversal is a performance issue, then the container structure itself is probably the problem. This is where hash tables help. That might not solve your specific problem, of course. I actually can't remember the last time I wrote a tree for real work.

Comment: @user3134575 *I noticed that the tree traversal part was the biggest bottleneck in my code so I need to speed that part as much as I can.* -- Are you running a release, optimized version, or a debug / unoptimized version?  If you're running a debug version, then please run a release version.  Timing a debug version is pointless.

Comment: With question 2 (early exit recursion), there is little/no speed improvement because you call the non-early exit recursive version, instead of recursing on `recursive2`. The time spent calling `rand` may also be excessive.

Comment: It's important to remember that most thoughts about algorithms and data structures are regarding data sizes approaching infinity.  Your data set is essentially zero.  Also, that is **VERY MUCH** not how you do microbenchmarks.   You're going to get garbage results.  Use http://quickbench.com/ and proper memory mangling techniques to get real results.  Are you sure your loops are even executing any code and not just being elided for not having visible outputs?

Comment: @xaxxon That link doesn't go where you think it does.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it but now the early break recursive function is even worse! Though indeed the rand function might be too expensive here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie its a release version, optimized for speed. I'm using visual studio compiler.

Comment: @xaxxon that is not a micro-benchmark for me! The code I posted here represents what I'm trying to do with my program except that in my full version code I'm dealing with a variable depth tree that on average might be 2 times deeper than what I posted here. The speed characteristics of the version I posted here is very similar to the program that I'm currently dealing with.

Comment: @user3134575 If your real code is also using arena-allocated nodes, then visiting every node by looping on the **arena** itself instead of recurring down the tree is going to be as efficient as possible. i.e just do `for(auto& node : nodes) {if (node.left == -1) {node.count++;}}`

Comment: @Frank arena-allocated is new for me, thanks for point it out. I'll try to read about it and see what can I change in my code to use it for more efficiency. The posted code is 90% percent similar to my actual code except that instead of nodes[node].count++, I'm comparing nodes[node].id to an external data and breaking it when the comparison meets a certain value e.g if(nodes[node].id == data[i]) { do something } else { break; }

Comment: @Frank, oh I see what you meant. The nature of the program I'm dealing  with and its interface do require me to traverse down from the root node toward the leaf nodes and then compare the leaf node ids to an external data, I have no way around that unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tree you are traversing is so small compared to the number of iterations you are running that managing the dynamic memory of the stack object dwarves any gains you *think* (we'll revisit that later) you are getting from doing it in a loop.

Let's try and remove that memory allocation overhead and see what happens to the speeds.

For reference, this is what I get out of your code as posted on my local Visual Studio  x64-Release build.

```
recursion:60
recursion with early-break:70
loop:2088
```

First off, `std::stack` uses `std::deque`, which is not great for small stacks. Switching to a vector-backed stack should makes things better. Since it's a one-line change, there's no reason to at least try it:

```
std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> stack;

recursion:58
recursion with early-break:68
loop:1853
```

And it does! It's not earth-shattering, but it's a good sign that we're on the right track. If we were worried about the time it takes to do one big traversal, that would probably be good enough. But what we care about is doing `10000000` tiny traversals, so we need to go further than that: Get rid of the memory allocation altogether:

```
// I "could" allocate the data as a local variable, 
// but then it would be on the stack, completely defeating the purpose.
// This would normally be a recyclable heap-based chunk of memory passed to
// the function.
std::array<int, 50> g_stack; // just for the example, don't actually do this.
void loop(int node) {
  auto top = g_stack.begin();
  auto push = [&](int v) {*(top++) = v;};
  auto pop = [&]() {--top;};

  push(node);
  while (top != g_stack.begin()) {
    node = *(top-1);
    pop();
    if (nodes[node].left == -1) {
      nodes[node].count++;
    }
    else {
      push(nodes[node].right);
      push(nodes[node].left);
    }
  }
}

recursion:61
recursion with early-break:68
loop:65
```

Now we're talking! But it still doesn't beat recursion. What's going on here?

The premise that a loop is always faster than using recursion is simply not universally true.

The primary advantage of a loop-based approach over recursion is not speed, it's that it addresses the biggest problem of recursion: the possibility of running out of stack space. By using a loop, you are capable of "recursing" much, much deeper than recursive function calls, because the stack of operation lives on the heap, which typically has a lot more room available.

Sometimes a compiler does a better job with loop code than with recursion, resulting in a faster runtime, but it's never a given.

Comment: "addresses the biggest problem of recursion: running out of stack space. " I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: @xaxxon I don't think getting into tail-call optimization minutia is appropriate for the scope of this question. And beyond that, in a case like OP's where the loop algorithm is the exact same, but with the stack in manually managed memory instead of being handled by the system, it really is the only difference. We are not talking about recursive fib() vs iterative fib() here, but about the same algorithm implemented in two different ways.

Comment: Is the code in the question even running the code inside the loops?  A quick glance looks like it may just be being elided completely.

Comment: @xaxxon It's not elided away. There's a clear side-effect in there.

Comment: You can also see it in the asembly: https://godbolt.org/z/a7z8e4Gzx. It's a bit of a mess because of the inlining all over the place,  but there is a clear entry into recusive(int) from main in the .L174 and.L176 sections.

Comment: I was confused by the coloration in one spot.. but what is the visible side effect?  I never did see it.

Comment: @xaxxon they increment the count on the node if it has a non-"null" left child, which is an entry in a `std::vector<>` so it alters allocated memory in a context where heap-elision can't be performed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I will try this in my program and see what a difference it makes since my program have deeper trees than the posted example. One question, your comment in the code states that I shouldn't do (std::array<int, 50> g_stack) but if I know the maximum depth of my trees, what is the problem if I use std::array<int, max_expected> g_stack; ?

Comment: I thought memory allocation was questionable in terms of whether it was considered external behavior or not.

Comment: @xaxxon Well, in this case, it's not the allocation per-se, but the fact that allocated memory is being modified. For the compiler to optimize that away, it needs to be able to prove that the memory will not be read by anything. That's a surprisingly tough bar to clear because there it's blind to code living in other TUs, so as soon as any pointer gets handed off to anything, or put in a global variable, any batch of writes to that memory kinda has to be treated as a side effect.

Comment: @user3134575 I just meant that using a global variable for this is not a good idea, because it makes the function non-reentrant.